# Get part of url with conditions

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds, regex-group

Based on this example: `http://example.com/cat1/tag/this%20is%20page/cat2`, i need to make a regex to get `/tag/<nextSegment>` only if this pattern is followed or preceded by other segments, not if is alone.

The result that i need is always: `http://example.com/tag/<fowardSegment>` only if `/tag/<fowardSegment>` is preceded or followed from other segments or characters not allowed.

I tried with this regex: [((?:/[A-Za-z0-9-]+)+)?(/tag/[A-Za-z0-9-%]+)+(/.*)?](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/2) but the pattern is catched also when it's alone (as you can see last example string in link).

Comment: I don't find your question clear. It would probably also benefit from some examples strings (matching and non-matching).

Comment: I'm sorry, i added some example strings in link..

Comment: Please include it in the question, link content is often ignored.

Comment: can you post expected results

Comment: Which strings should be matched, and which ones should not? Please add these sets to the question.

Comment: I added other informations :) @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Try [`\b(\/tag\/[A-Za-z0-9-%]+)\/.*$`](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/4)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The second and third example strings must be catched also. Also, the first example string not catch previous segments.

Comment: I wonder why `http://example.com/cat1/subcat3/subcat4/tag/this%20is%20pageasdasd` should be matched. There is no more subparts after `tag/<part>`. See https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/5

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew 'cause in `http://example.com/cat1/subcat3/subcat4/tag/this%20is%20pageasdasd` the pattern `/tag/this%20is%20pageasdasd` is preceded by `/cat1/subcat3/subcat4`. As i wrote in thread, the result that i need is always: `http://example.com/tag/<fowardSegment>` **only if** `/tag/<fowardSegment>` **is preceded or followed from other segments or characters not allowed.**

Comment: Ok, I'd recommend a kind of a match what you do not need and capture what you need regex. See [`^(?:https?:\/\/)?[^\/]+\/tag\/[^\/]+$|(\/tag\/[^\/]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/6), you will need to adjust the code for it since you only need Group 1 value.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You match only pattern `/tag/<segment>` but if you see my regex: [link](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/2) i catch all except domain name though groups (left segments before pattern `/tag/<segment>`and after) but the last string example, must not be matched cause `/tag/<segment>` is not preceded or followed by other segments or characters.. I'd recommend to see substitution part also, it can help you to understand what i need.

Comment: Add the exception pattern at the start of your pattern, see [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/7).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Almost perfect! But last string example `http://example.com/tag/this` must not be matched!

Comment: But you should not care whether or not it is matched. Only what is captured matters. What is the code?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I&amp;#39;m making some redirects, so `http://example.com/tag/this`- `http://example.com/tag/this%20%is%20page`- `/tag/this`- `http://example.com (understood as domain name)` must be not considered, seems like my regex, except last string example (that is the problem) [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/2)

Comment: Try something like https://regex101.com/r/gwK1Hg/1.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew in your regex, you **must not match domain name and `/tag/sd-asd`** Check my example: [this fiddle](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/2)

Comment: :) You won't be able to not match the domain. Unless you use .NET.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Why not, i make it in my example..

Comment: Yeah, and you match what you do not want, too.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep, so isn't possible to make it?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you want is this: `/(?<=https?:\/\/.*)((?:\/[\w]+)*)((?:\/tag)(?:\/[\w%?=.-]+){2,})$/`

**EDIT**

As I was made aware in the comments below of the extra ones that need matching:

```
/(?<=https?:\/\/.*|[\w_.]+)(?:((?:\/[\w]+)+)((?:\/tag)(?:\/[\w%?=.-]+))|((?:\/[\w]+))*((?:\/tag)(?:\/[\w%?=.-]+){2,}))$/
```

An example usage in JS:

```js
let regex = /(?<=https?:\/\/.*|[\w_.]+)(?:((?:\/[\w]+)+)((?:\/tag)(?:\/[\w%?=.-]+))|((?:\/[\w]+))*((?:\/tag)(?:\/[\w%?=.-]+){2,}))$/,
  examples = ["http://example.com/cat1/subcat3/subcat4/tag/this%20is%20page/asdasda?start=130/asdasdasd", // #Should Match
    "http://example.com/cat1/subcat3/subcat4/tag/this%20is%20pageasdasd", // Should Match
    "example.it/news/tag/this%is%20n%page?adsadsadasd", // Should Match
    "http://example.com/tag/thispage/asdasdasd.-?asds=", // Should Match
    "http://example.com/tag/this%20is%20page/asdasd", // Should Match
    "http://example.com/tag/this", // Should Not Match
    "/tag/this/asdads" // Should Not Match
  ]

examples.forEach((example) => {
  if (example.match(regex)) {
    let matches = regex.exec(example),
        category = matches[1] !== undefined ? matches[1] : matches[3] !== undefined ? matches[3] : "No category",
        tag = matches[2] === undefined ? matches[4] : matches[2];
        
    console.log(`Full String: "${example}"\nCategory: "${category}"\nTag: "${tag}"`)
  }
})
```

See it on [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/9)

Comment: Not at all. If you saw my example: [link to example](https://regex101.com/r/G57QT0/2), i match all right except last string example that must not be matched cause /tag/<segment> is not preceded or followed by other segments or characters.

Comment: @Kouga See my edit, it should now do what you want it to